# Broadcast receiver not work on Android4.0 emulator

Tags: android

I create a project which only includes one receiver. Some codes are like below:

```
<receiver android:name=".InputReceive" android.enabled = "true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.myproject.BackButton" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class InputReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    String action = arg1.getAction();
    if(action.equals("com.myproject.BackButton")){
        back();
    }
}

private void back(){
    Log.e("wwq", "back");
}
```

}

When I run command in cmd

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.myproject.BackButton
```

No log such as 'back' appear in logcat. Receiver no response.
Log is below:

```
12-12 16:33:05.431: W/ActivityManager(98): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{415fcd58 com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_POLL} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@4135ff18, started 10051ms ago
12-12 16:33:05.431: W/ActivityManager(98): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{41360160 ReceiverList{413600e8 98 system/1000 local:4135ff18}}
12-12 16:33:15.609: W/ActivityManager(98): finishReceiver called but no pending broadcasts
```

This issue only happened on Android 4.0 emulator. Who knows that what changed about Broadcast receiver in Android 4.0. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your application is installed, the user need to launch an activity of yours manually before any of your `BroadcastReceivers` will have an effect, as of Android 3.1.

Also, note that it is `android:enabled`, not `android.enabled`.

Comment: But I run this apk on GB2.3.3, it works well. Dose this issue only happen on Android 3.0 or higher version ?

Comment: @vicky: As I wrote in my answer, this change occurred in Android 3.1.

Comment: I found that article that explains the issue and suggests a workaround for that: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Its a parental monitoring app. On a SMS response it should start. But the broad cast receiver is not working at all. My application does not uses any activity only services. Please guide me to the solution, I have been searching it for days.

Comment: @AhmadShahwaiz: Add an activity. After all, you need one for the license agreement, terms of service, configuration, online help, etc. And, you need one for your app to work, as described in my answer, [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html), etc.

Comment: Alright, so we MUST have atleast 1 activity for the broadcast receivers to work, can we do something that we place a button on the application and upon clicking the app hides or disappears saying uninstall but still hiding. Would it work?

Comment: Also on the Rooted Android phones 3.1+ the receiver should work (without the activities), as it overrides the security?